# asp.net c# mysql square brackets in select statement

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am having an issue with the way asp.net/c# is generating mySQL select statements when setting up my datasource control.

I am pretty sure I have a setting set wrong, but cannot figure out what it is.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:demers_dbConnectionString3 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:demers_dbConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test_table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As you can see, the brackets around test_table are square, and this statement throws a syntax error.

When I manually change the brackets to:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:demers_dbConnectionString3 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:demers_dbConnectionString3.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM (test_table)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The error goes away and my page runs.

I will have to create a lot of mySQL links as I develop my site, so I was hoping to fix the setting that I have wrong.

Ideas???

This is the associated config file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="demers_dbConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=MYID;password=MYPASSWORD;database=demers_db"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of those `[]`; since you are using `MySQL` you should use backtique (`) for escaping. Your select command should look like

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM `test_table`"
```

(or) just below since there is no spaces in your table name

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM test_table"
```

Also make sure that you are using MySQL connector provider `ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`

Comment: Thank you for that, I used SQL Server in school! However, do you know why asp.net is not formatting the code correctly to begin with???

Comment: Most probably, while configuring SQL data source you have selected SQL Server connection provider instead of MySQL. If answer helped then don't forge to accept the answer.

Comment: Here is my web.config:

Comment: Per your web.config I see there is a connection string named `demers_dbConnectionString` but in your code you are using `demers_dbConnectionString3`?

Comment: Sorry I was playing with redoing the connection. You told me a good part of what I was doing wrong, but I still need to find that setting. I will poke at it for awhile. Thanks for the help.